# error importing fixed-width text file

Tags: r, csv

I have data in fixed-width format that I want to import in R:

```
Year D M  St  Value
1980 1 1  G1  0.00
1980 1 2  G1  0.00
1980 1 3  G1  0.00
1980 1 4  G1  0.00
1980 1 5  G1  1.93
1980 1 6  G1  0.00
1980 1 7  G1  3.40
1980 1 8  G1  0.00
1980 1 9  G1  0.00
1980 110  G1  0.00
1980 111  G1  0.00
1980 112  G1  0.00
1980 113  G1  0.00
1980 114  G1  0.00
1980 115  G1  0.00
1980 116  G1  0.00
1980 117  G1  0.00
1980 118  G1  0.00
1980 119  G1 15.75
```

Column 1 is the year, 2nd column is the date, third is Month, 4th is station and 5th is value. However, the problem is after 9th month, column 2 and and column 3 get merged and hence when I try to import this "blank space" separated file in R I get the error message: `line 10 did not have 5 elements`. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: what command are you running that produces that error?

Comment: sample of the file to be imported : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybi2ypsw61fwwnj/SimDemo_Daily_Sim001.dat?dl=0

Comment: While this is already solved: the data is not tab-delimited (nor "blank space" separated), but fixed-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your data. The `read.fwf` function will do the job.

```
dat <- read.fwf("SimDemo_Daily_Sim001.dat", widths = c(4,2,2,4,6), as.is=T)
```

To see more about `read.fwf`, type `?read.fwf` in R console.

Comment: does not work , when i try to import file : a sample of my import file is provided here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybi2ypsw61fwwnj/SimDemo_Daily_Sim001.dat?dl=0